# Vertex Biconnected and Edge Biconnected misconception

Tags: algorithm, graph

A connected graph is vertex biconnected if there is no vertex whose removal disconnects the graph. A connected graph is edge biconnected if there is no edge whose removal disconnects the graph.
Give a proof or counterexample for each for the following statements:

(a) A vertex biconnected graph is edge biconnected.

(b) An edge biconnected graph is vertex biconnected.

For A)My attempt is that it should be the case, since I don't see how removing a vertex will affect the biconnection of the edge.

For B)My attempt is NO, since if we have a bridge, connecting two graphs, removing that edge will no longer have the graph vertex biconnected.

Perhaps I am totally wrong here, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simple [counterexample](https://www.math.umass.edu/~tevelev/zuz.png) for (b)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff is my (a) right?

Comment: @user2302617 You didn't offer proof for (a). You offered intuition, which is an important part of education, but irrelevant in a formal context.

Comment: @G.Bach I drew a couple of graphs, and since it was vertex bi-connected,i.e the removal of a vetex does not disconnect it, I then tried removing edges, and it still was NOT disconnected. I don't see how removing a vertex can ever disconnect a graph.

Comment: @user2302617 That isn't proof though. You can give 10000 examples where it holds, that does not prove a general statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof for a): by contradiction. Let G = (V,E) be vertex biconnected. Assume it is not edge biconnected. Then there exists an edge e = {v,w} we can remove such that G' = (V, E \ {e}) is disconnected. But then we can also remove v or w from G and disconnect the graph (since the removal of either end vertex of an edge will also remove that edge), which is a contradiction to G being vertex biconnected; thus G must also be edge biconnected.

Comment: I learn better from visual graphs, I am having a hard time following you.

Comment: Sadly, visualization will not help you learn how to prove something. It can only help you to understand the intuition behind a proof. The idea behind this one is: if I can disconnect the graph by removing an edge, I can also disconnect the graph by removing one of the vertices the edge is incident with. So that proves ´not edge biconnected => not vertex biconnected´ which is the contrapositive of what you want to prove.

Comment: You really shouldn't be accepting answers you don't understand though; if something isn't clear, it is better to ask for clarification in a comment.

Comment: I accepted it because, hey, I accept that what you are saying makes sense, but I am just not able to entirely follow you and was looking for a visual representation. In fact, I was just asking for a visual representation so I can entirely understand it.

Comment: Here's a [picture](http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/7620/illustrations.png); A and B are supposed to be connected subgraphs, and except for e there is no edge running between them. You see that the graph becomes disconnected if you remove e, so it isn't biconnected. But then that also happens if you remove v or w. Could you follow the answer to your other question?

Comment: now I get it. Thank you